# PHP implode limit bug?

Tags: php, arrays, implode

I've got a script that creates an array with around 40,000 entries, PHP arrays have no limit except the memory of the server...

However the PHP function `implode()` simply does not output anything, when trying to implode an array of around 40,000 entries into a string. Each array entry has about a sentence worth of a-Z characters. No memory errors, no errors at all!

Can anyone confirm this?

I'm not sure its possible to post examples!

**EDIT** (2013-06-03):

I can confirm that the PHP memory limit was set to -1 and PHP errors were to to E_ALL. There where no errors and simply no output. **This seems to be an bug with PHP of some sort.**

I was using `echo implode("<br>\n", $myLogArr);` with did not error or output anything, I've mananage to get the correct expected result by using `foreach ($myLogArr as $line) echo $line."<br>\n";`

Comment: Did you check this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13845927/possible-limitation-of-implode-function-in-php

Comment: Don't you reach the `memory_limit` set in `php.ini` ?

Comment: set_time_limit to check also.... put set_time_limit(0); at the beginning of your code then try to run it.

Comment: Check [this fiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/j7e-bb4) it works

Answer (score 1):

The following works just fine - with 50,000 entries.

```
<?php
$arr = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < 50000; $i++) {
    $arr[] = str_shuffle('This sentance is of average length, which The Internet says is about 14.2 words.');
}
echo implode(PHP_EOL, $arr);
```

I would suggest increasing [error_reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) and attempting to debug this further.

Anthony.

Answer (score 0):

memory_limit to -1 and then execute your script in try catch block

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = str_repeat("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz,",1000000);
$array = explode(",", $string);
var_dump(sizeof($array), strlen(implode(",", $array)));
```

outputs:

```
int 1000001
int 53000000
```

OP, can you please show your code?